# setOnClickListener() is not executing completely on single click

Tags: java, android, android-studio, executor

I am trying to trigger a piece of code on button click using `View.setOnClickListener`.
My code includes two `OkHttp` requests going to Google Places API which returns JSON files. I parse them and then place a call on a phone number extracted using the APIs.

Now, when I click on the button, the code is executed only partially. **It executes the first request and returns the Place ID of the place I need. But, the phone call is not placed.**

On using Logcat, we can see that the place ID is extracted, but only when I click the button once again, the complete code is executed and I see double output, i.e. the phone number extracted is logged twice.

Please help me in clearing this execution flow problem and making sure that the **single click is enough to request the 2 APIs and then place the call also.**

Below is the code for the `onCreate` method of my `Activity`

```java
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        checkPerms(this);
        simpleLocation = new SimpleLocation(this, true);
        tv1 = findViewById(R.id.tv1);
        tv2 = findViewById(R.id.tv2);
        bt = findViewById(R.id.bt);
        String apikey = getString(R.string.apikey);
        bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                simpleLocation.beginUpdates();
                final double latitude = simpleLocation.getLatitude();
                final double longitude = simpleLocation.getLongitude();
                tv1.setText(String.valueOf(latitude));
                tv2.setText(String.valueOf(longitude));
                ExecutorService ex = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
                final FutureTask<String> result1 = (FutureTask<String>) ex.submit(new Callable<String>() {
                    public String call(){
                        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
                        Request request1 =new Request.Builder()
                                .url(URLBuilder1(latitude, longitude, apikey))
                                .get()
                                .build();
                        try{
                            Response response = client.newCall(request1).execute();
                            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response.body().string());
                            pid = jsonObject.getJSONArray("results").getJSONObject(0).getString("place_id");
                        } catch (IOException | JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            Log.d("JSON 1", e.getLocalizedMessage());
                        }
                        return pid;
                    }
                });
                try {
                    PID = result1.get();
                    Log.d("TAG", PID);
                }
                catch (ExecutionException | InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                final FutureTask<String> result2 = (FutureTask<String>) ex.submit(new Callable<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public String call() {
                        try {
                            OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
                            Request request2 = new Request.Builder()
                                    .url(URLBuilder2(apikey, pid))
                                    .get()
                                    .build();
                            Response response = client.newCall(request2).execute();
                            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(Objects.requireNonNull(response.body()).string());
                            phone = jsonObject.getJSONObject("result").getString("international_phone_number");
                            phone = phone.replace(" ", "");
                            Log.d("TAG", phone);
                        }
                        catch (IOException | JSONException e){
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        return phone;
                    }
                });
                try {
                    phone = result2.get();
                    Log.d("TAG", phone);
                }
                catch (ExecutionException | InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                Log.d("TAG", phone);
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                i.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + phone));
            }
        });
    }
```

p.s. I am a student developer who began Java for Android only 2 months ago, so any tips on code optimization or any other tips regarding bettering the code will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should nest the two requests.
So first you should run the first request. then right after you assign the pid variable you should start the second request. Then right after you assign the phone variable you should start the phone call intent.  Its simple as that. Second request should be inside the first request. Phone Call Intent should be inside the second request. I hope you'd understand.

In your code what happens is, before you receive the pid the second request is also executed. Its better if you could use Volley Library by Google

Example Code

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_about);
context = this;

checkPerms(this);
simpleLocation = new SimpleLocation(this, true);
tv1 = findViewById(R.id.tv1);
tv2 = findViewById(R.id.tv2);
bt = findViewById(R.id.bt);
String apikey = getString(R.string.apikey);
bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {@Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
    simpleLocation.beginUpdates();
    final double latitude = simpleLocation.getLatitude();
    final double longitude = simpleLocation.getLongitude();
    tv1.setText(String.valueOf(latitude));
    tv2.setText(String.valueOf(longitude));
    ExecutorService ex = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
    final FutureTask < String > result1 = (FutureTask < String > ) ex.submit(new Callable < String > () {
      public String call() {
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        Request request1 = new Request.Builder().url(URLBuilder1(latitude, longitude, apikey)).get().build();
        try {
          Response response = client.newCall(request1).execute();
          JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response.body().string());
          pid = jsonObject.getJSONArray("results").getJSONObject(0).getString("place_id");

          final FutureTask < String > result2 = (FutureTask < String > ) ex.submit(new Callable < String > () {@Override
            public String call() {
              try {
                OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
                Request request2 = new Request.Builder().url(URLBuilder2(apikey, pid)).get().build();
                Response response = client.newCall(request2).execute();
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(Objects.requireNonNull(response.body()).string());
                phone = jsonObject.getJSONObject("result").getString("international_phone_number");
                phone = phone.replace(" ", "");
                Log.d("TAG", phone);

                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                i.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + phone));

              }
              catch(IOException | JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
              }
              return phone;
            }
          });

        } catch(IOException | JSONException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
          Log.d("JSON 1", e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
        return pid;
      }
    });
  }
});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatevely you can use OkHttp in async manner. For example:

```
            ExecutorService ex = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
            ex.submit(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
                    Request request1 = new Request.Builder()
                            .url(URLBuilder1(latitude, longitude, apikey))
                            .get()
                            .build();

                    client.newCall(request1).enqueue(new Callback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NotNull Call call, @NotNull IOException e) {
                            //logging
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(@NotNull Call call, @NotNull Response response) throws IOException {
                            try {
                                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response.body().string());
                                pid = jsonObject.getJSONArray("results").getJSONObject(0).getString("place_id");
                                Log.d("TAG", pid);

                            } catch (IOException | JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                                Log.d("JSON 1", e.getLocalizedMessage());
                            }
                            Request request2 = new Request.Builder()
                                    .url(URLBuilder2(apikey, pid))
                                    .get()
                                    .build();
                            OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
                            client.newCall(request2).enqueue(new Callback() {
                                @Override
                                public void onFailure(@NotNull Call call, @NotNull IOException e) {

                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onResponse(@NotNull Call call, @NotNull Response response) throws IOException {

                                    try {
                                        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(Objects.requireNonNull(response.body()).string());
                                        phone = jsonObject.getJSONObject("result").getString("international_phone_number");
                                        phone = phone.replace(" ", "");
                                        Log.d("TAG", phone);
                                        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                                        i.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + phone));
                                    } catch (IOException | JSONException e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
```

Note: I did not run the code above, just giving an example.

Instead of `client.newCall(request1).execute();` which runs synchronically, you can use:

```
client.newCall(request1).enqueue(new Callback() {
                                @Override
                                public void onFailure(@NotNull Call call, @NotNull IOException e) {
                                    //if request fails then this method gets executed 
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onResponse(@NotNull Call call, @NotNull Response response) throws IOException {
                                    //response is coming as method parameter "response" 
                                }
                            });
```

which is completely async.